# Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. please help me to solve this error

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, json, reactjs

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

const Regsiterme = () => {
  const [name, setName] = useState("");
  const [password, setPassword] = useState("");
  const [email, setEmail] = useState("");

  async function signUp() {
    let item = { name, password, email };

    let result = await fetch("http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/userRegister", {
      method: "POST",
      body: JSON.stringify(item),
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        Accept: "application/json",
      },
    });
    result = await result.json();
    localStorage.setItem("user-info", JSON.stringify(result));
  }
  return (
    <>
      <h1 className="text-center">Regsiter Form</h1>

      <div class="mb-3 col-sm-6 offset-sm-3">
        <input
          type="text"
          value={name}
          onChange={(e) => setName(e.target.value)}
          class="form-control"
          placeholder="Enter Your Full Name"
        />
        <br /> <br />
        <input
          type="password"
          value={password}
          onChange={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)}
          class="form-control"
          placeholder="Enter Your Password"
        />
        <br /> <br />
        <input
          type="email"
          value={email}
          onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)}
          class="form-control"
          placeholder="Enter Your Email"
        />
        <br /> <br />
      </div>
      <div class="mb-3 col-sm-6 offset-sm-3">
        <button onClick={signUp} type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
          Submit
        </button>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default Regsiterme;
```

Comment: How do you use this component?

Comment: I realise this isn't solving your problem, and I apologise for that.. but. Forms are quite difficult to get right in general if you're building stuff from scratch, so I would encourage you to have a look at packages like [React Hook Form](https://react-hook-form.com/) or [Formik](https://formik.org/) – both are great, and have solved a lot of things that you haven't implemented quite yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hooks can only be used in Functional Components. I think tweaking how you declare signUp should solve your problem.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

const Regsiterme = () => {
  const [name, setName] = useState("");
  const [password, setPassword] = useState("");
  const [email, setEmail] = useState("");

  const signUp = async () => {
    let item = { name, password, email };

    let result = await fetch("http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/userRegister", {
      method: "POST",
      body: JSON.stringify(item),
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        Accept: "application/json",
      },
    });
    result = await result.json();
    localStorage.setItem("user-info", JSON.stringify(result));
  }

  return (
    <>
      <h1 className="text-center">Regsiter Form</h1>

      <div class="mb-3 col-sm-6 offset-sm-3">
        <input
          type="text"
          value={name}
          onChange={(e) => setName(e.target.value)}
          class="form-control"
          placeholder="Enter Your Full Name"
        />
        <br /> <br />
        <input
          type="password"
          value={password}
          onChange={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)}
          class="form-control"
          placeholder="Enter Your Password"
        />
        <br /> <br />
        <input
          type="email"
          value={email}
          onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)}
          class="form-control"
          placeholder="Enter Your Email"
        />
        <br /> <br />
      </div>
      <div class="mb-3 col-sm-6 offset-sm-3">
        <button onClick={signUp} type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
          Submit
        </button>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default Regsiterme;
```